# Display multiple polygon on Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-leaflet

I have a model with a `gis_models.GeometryField`.

```
class MyModel(django.db.models):
   area = gis_models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm displaying this model on Django admin but i'm using https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet library.

I already have 100+ rows in the database. when I open the admin page for any of those entries, I'm able to see a polygon being draw. that's perfect!
take another case where I have to add a new polygon from the admin page. I am able to draw the map and save the entry. it works as expected.  I can see the polygon on the map next time I open that entry on the map.

the problem is when I add a new polygon I  don't know what polygons are already there in the DB. so sometimes I add a new polygon that overlaps with existing ones. I was thinking of displaying all the available polygons on the map so that next time I add a new one I won't touch those points on the map.  how can we display all the polygons (MultiPolygon) just for the /add/ page?

PS: I couldn't find the method that I can override in Django admin class to render all the polygons. also, I couldn't find the relevant question on StackOverflow or any other source. so please if you think I didn't search enough please point me to the link that you think would be helpful to me for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right way. The best solution is to create your own template for viewing your spatial data. Visit for example https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet. Another solution is to connect your spatial database to a program such as Quantum GIS, and in this way, you can do CRUD operation with your database.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use spatial database (I recommend Postgres with PostGIS extension )

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-postgresql-django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'polygon',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'*******',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    } }
```

2.Add django.contrib.gis into your installed apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .......
    'django.contrib.gis',
    .....
]
```

3. create a model

   #models.py

   ```
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models


    class Polygon(models.Model):
         area=models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
   ```